# Restrict on creating new Record by Record Type

Tags: apex, profile, record-type

I am having a Custom object "`Service_Type__c`".

There are 3 record Types : Author, Consultant, Publish

I want when record type is "Author", user of a perticular profile can't create a record. It will throw error "You  are not authorized to Create Record with this record type".

Is it possible in Salesforce by configuration ?

Note : `Service_Type__c` and opportunity object have relationship, so we can create `Service_Type__c` record in the Opportunity Related list.

2nd way in which we can create `Service_Type__c` record is click on the object tab and click on New button.

Above scenaio is applicable for Clicking on New button. If User is clicking on Tab and clicking on New tab, then User will get the error. User is supposed to creat the record via opportunity object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just don't assign the 'Author' record type to that particular profile:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I have updated my Question above. We cant remove the Record type from the profile. If we do then user from that profile can't see the record type at all.

However, if user is creating the record from opportunit Record, he should see all 3 Record types.

Comment: Unsure what you mean by "can't see"? Visibility on records with that record type is not handled by profiles, so he could see them if you want to. The only thing he does not see, is that record type as an available one on creation. But this is a way more user friendly experience than showing it, but throwing an error when he clicks it either way.

Comment: Yes visibility of Record types is handeled by avaliability of Record types, which we can configure in the profile setting.

Can't see means, the record type wont be visible for the Profile.

I want, Record type has to be visible, but if user is creating record from the tab and record type is "Author", then he wont be able to create the record.

in 2nd Scenario : If user is creating `Service_Type__c` record from opportunity record type then he can create record, even though Record type os "Author".

Comment: No, it is not, as I stated before:

`A record type assignment on a user’s profile or permission set does not determine whether a user can view a record with that record type; rather, the record type assignment simply specifies that the user can use that record type when creating or editing a record.`